# Sanskrit non-translatables

Tags: discussion, languages

Every language encodes within it a unique culture and a world view. This site being an English site, our questions and answers are in English. But certain words lose meaning when translated to English.

For example,

- Sin is not bad karma or paap
- Atman is not soul
- Jati-varna system is not caste system

By using these English words we distorting the actual meaning of these words and the philosophy behind them. Where possible I feel we should use the actual sanskrit word instead of using it's English (mis)translation.

Refer this document for many Sanskrit non-translatables

http://rajivmalhotra.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/SanskritNonTranslatables.pdf

Comment: 'Brahma' or 'Brahman'another example I think...

Comment: a probable solution is to mention the word in both Sanskrit (original) and for the general public English. That way at least the learned can discern the intention of author.

Comment: The same is with `Mythology` tag. We can have some better tag instead of it.

Comment: @Sandeep, Mythology is better kept as Itihasa or Purana.

Comment: dharma is also an example.