# Tags lacking Hindu words like papa or papam

Tags: feature-request

I recently post a question about if Sanskrit words like papa and atma can be translated to mean sin and soul. If it is appropriate or not. When I clicked the "Post Your Question" button, I received an error asking me to select a tag, I was forced to add sin tag, because there was nothing remotely similar to papa or papam.

As this is Hindu section, shouldn't words like papa or papam be used?

Comment: Though many Sanskrit words are [non-translable](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/240/277) however we are usually using closer equivalent English terms so-that visitors can understand.

Comment: This is English Language site. Users will be mainly who are English readers. Because the words in Hinduism are not easy to understand, we use English equivalent. This is not forcing people not to use Hindu words. Sin is near equivalent of Papam.